# Minio does not seem to recognize TLS/https certificates

Tags: ssl, minio

Im search now for hours to make minio work with self-signed tls certs using docker.
accroding to the documentation certs just need to be placed at /root/.minio/certs/CAs or /root/.minio/ inside the minio container

I tried both with no success

This is how I start minio (using saltstack):

```
minio:
  docker_container.running:
    - order: 10
    - hostname: backup
    - container_name: backup
    - binds:
      - /root/backup:/data
      - /srv/salt/minio/certs:/root/.minio
    - image: minio/minio:latest
    - port_bindings:
      - 10.10.10.1:9000:443
    - environment:
      - MINIO_BROWSER=off
      - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=BlaBlaBla
      - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=BlaBlaBla
    - privileged: false
    - entrypoint: sh
    - command: -c 'mkdir -p /data/backup && /usr/bin/minio server --address ":443" /data'
    - restart_policy: always
```

If I do "docker logs minio" I just get to see http instead of https:

> Endpoint: http://172.17.0.3:443  http://127.0.0.1:443

Both keys public and privat are mounted at the correct location inside the container but they not seem to recognize ...

can smb help, do I need to add some extra parameter here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Per the docs (https://docs.minio.io/docs/how-to-secure-access-to-minio-server-with-tls.html), your keys must be named public.crt and private.key, respectively, and mounted at `~/.minio/certs` (e.g. `/root/.minio/certs`).  The CA's directory is for public certs of other servers you want to trust, for example in a distributed setup.

Answer (score 0):

you doesn't  need to setup cert in minio. Use nginx server then reverse proxy minio port as like 127.0.0.1:9000 port . then use cert file in nginx server block . your all problem solved