# SSL encryption with MinIO does not work, its only possible unencrypted

Tags: ssl, certificate, minio, ubuntu-22.04

I run a sandboxed environment with 3 Virtual Servers on a 10.1.0.0/24 network.

```
Server_0: Windows 2019 as a Jumphost with a public and a 10.1.0.x IP
Server_1: Ubuntu 22.04 running Apache SOLR
Server_2: Ubuntu 22.04 Running Tomcat9 and MinIO
```

When accessing

```
https://Server_1:8983/solr      SOLR Admin Page is shown on Server_0  
https://Server_2:8443/          Tomcat9 page is shown on Server_0  
https://Server_2:9000 or 9001   MinIO-Console page is not shown on Server_0 (SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG)
http://Server_2:9000 or 9001    MinIO-Console page is shown on Server_0
```

The Installation is default and exactly done like described here: [https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/index.html?ref=con]

```
systemctl status minio
minio.service - MinIO
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/minio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-02-23 11:21:32 UTC; 5s ago
Docs: https://docs.min.io
Process: 66959 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if \[ -z "${MINIO_VOLUMES}" \]; then echo "Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/defau\>
Main PID: 66960 (minio)
Tasks: 7 (limit: 9492)
Memory: 83.6M
CPU: 339ms
CGroup: /system.slice/minio.service
└─66960 /usr/local/bin/minio server --certs-dir /var/minio/.minio/certs --address :9000 --console-address :9001

minio\[66960\]: Copyright: 2015-2023 MinIO, Inc.
minio\[66960\]: License: GNU AGPLv3 <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html>
minio\[66960\]: Version: RELEASE.2023-01-31T02-24-19Z (go1.19.4 linux/amd64)
minio\[66960\]: Status:         1 Online, 0 Offline.
minio\[66960\]: API: http://10.1.0.19:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000
minio\[66960\]: Console: http://10.1.0.19:9001 http://127.0.0.1:9001
minio\[66960\]: Documentation: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/index.html
minio\[66960\]: Warning: The standard parity is set to 0. This can lead to data loss.
```

- Installed RootCA and IntermediateCert with *dpkg* and updated with *update-ca.certificates*
- Created public.crt and public.key with openssl, compared checksums and verified all Certs and put them to the right cert-dir (yes, I stripped also the headers that it starts with -----BEGIN....)
- Port 9000/9001 is open , thus it works on the same port unencrypted.
- the /etc/default/minio file is correct (can be seen in the status)
- the /etc/systemd/minio.servive is default

...and yes, the Browser on Server_0 is configured with all the needed Certificates too.

Also checked here (e.g. [Minio does not seem to recognize TLS/https certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161424/minio-does-not-seem-to-recognize-tls-https-certificates,...))

I'm clueless what to check else, seems i forgot something stupid XD
I hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure why you stripped any headers from any certificate. I don't think that is a requirement we have.

What openssl command did you run to generate the certs? Have you tried this without modifying the certs after generation (outside of naming it appropriately)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There no such thing as `public.key` this is the typo you need to make sure the filenames are

- public.crt (your public key for the ECDSA private key)
- private.key (your private key - ECDSA key preferably)

This is the mistake you did

```
tree /var/minio/.minio/certs/
/var/minio/.minio/certs/
├── CAs
├── private.key
└── public.crt

1 directory, 2 files
```

And you shouldn't be touching your certs

> (yes, I stripped also the headers that it starts with -----BEGIN....)

By modifying them.

Answer (score 0):

Hell yes, you are right. 'Lazy Me' only changed the file extension when exporting the keys, but not the name.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in public.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out public.crt
openssl pkcs12 -in public.p12 -clcerts -nocerts -nodes -out public.key
openssl rsa -in public.key -out public.key
```

I removed the optional Bag and Key Attributes from the file, which are generated when converting with openssl. Means that the certs contain only this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    ...a-bunge-of-letters-and-numbers...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Works now after renaming to private.key

Thanks a lot and sorry for my laziness ;)